# How to connect to MySQL Database using sockets

Tags: php, android

My purpose is my android application sync real time to **MySQL** database and with any change in specific table, my recyclerView in android be refresh. someone told me to use sockets, how can i use **sockets**? is that the solution?

Comment: I think that that someone meant WebSockets not simple sockets. Check out [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you should NEVER directly connect to a remote db via a mobile app.  The reason:  you have to put your password in your app to do so.  Which means anyone with a copy of your app has the password to your database, and can do whatever they want to it.  The correct answer is to use a webservice, so the password to your database never leaves computers you control.

Comment: So what can I do? How can I sync my app to my database like chat messengers?

Comment: Webservice.  Start researching them.  Based on where you are now you have a lot of studying to do.

Comment: I know some php. do you have any example?

Comment: Look for "php rest service" on the net. Here's one overview: http://www.gajotres.net/best-available-php-restful-micro-frameworks/

Comment: @GabeSechan something that i forgot to say. I'm not putting my password in my app, i'm using Json to communicate with server, and in the server i have some php files to have my connection strings

Comment: You shouldn't even put it into your app in memory- ours a weakness that can be explored easily

Answer (score 0):

See https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/.

Notice that socket connections for MySQL are only available with unix servers. The connection string would look like that:

`Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
Protocol=socket;`

But: Do you really-really-really need a realtime sync? A delay of half a second is not okay? I would doubt that, especially thinking of an Android app and mobile network delays etc. I would NEVER connect to a database directly from an app.

Comment: I'm afraid to pressure the server with requests!

Comment: You should be more afraid of too many connections to your database server ;-) Use webservices like Gabe Sechan says. It is a good standard.